# Opening a specified folder using Intents for samsung explorer

Tags: android, android-intent

I am able to open the My files app but my need is to open a particular folder in My files . It shows me the folder for other File explorers. Below is my code taken from another post:

```
public void openFile(Uri data) {
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setDataAndType(data,"file/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

Intent sIntent = new Intent("com.sec.android.app.myfiles.PICK_DATA");
     // if you want any file type, you can skip next line 
    sIntent.putExtra("CONTENT_TYPE", "*/*"); 
    sIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    Intent chooserIntent;
    if (getPackageManager().resolveActivity(sIntent, 0) != null){
        // it is device with samsung file manager
        chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(sIntent, "Open folder");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,data.toString() );
    }
    else {
        chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open file");
    }

    try {
        startActivity(chooserIntent);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No suitable File Manager was found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can anyone help me out?

Comment: did you figure this out ? I have the same issue and cannot open a specific path.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to open specific folder with my Files application :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("com.sec.android.app.myfiles.VIEW");
        intent.putExtra("folderPath", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/myFolder/");
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have tried that and it does not work. It just brings you to the initial directory. Can you please share where you got that info from or where one can get information or an api for the intent extras you can use with Samsung's My Files app ?

Comment: I tried too many time to make this solution. You should check folder path again. Now, i still use this solution for my project.